# Emulator wrong screen resolution in Android Studio 1.3

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, screen-resolution

I have updated to Android Studio 1.3 and I'm trying to make a test with Nexus 5 which has a resolution of 1080px x 1920px and when I start the emulator the icons are too big and when I run my app which has a banner of 320x50. This banner is nearly as wide as the screen!

Here is the emulator without any application running, where you can see a very big icons on the screen.

[image]

And here is a screenshot with an app which has a banner test of 320x50px

[image]

If I select "No Skin" in Custom Skin Definition, it doesn't work for me. In the later image you can see it.

Another example, this is what I see and what I want to see in Android Studio to a Tablet Nexus 7:

[image]

And this is what I've got to a Tablet Nexus 7 in Android Emulator: it's too big. Why does this happen?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the Android Virtual Device Manager click "Create virtual device", select needed one and click the "Clone device" button. Then change "Default skin" to "No skin". Now save the profile and launch it.

Comment: Thank you, I have followed all your instrucctions but it still doesn't work to me :( I still get a wrong screen resolution :(

Comment: Are you sure you are launching the cloned device and not the default one?

Comment: Yes!!! I launched the cloned device and it didn't work!!! But, I have launched again the clone device and ... It works!!! :))) Maybe I have to restart Android Studio because I don't know what happend the first time that I launched the cloned device. So, that's all!!! Thank you so much @Alex Yeusiukou for your help!!!